# What does the function $n(\gamma , z_{0})$ denote in this version of Cauchy Integral Formula?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, cauchy-integral-formula

In my lecture notes, the Cauchy Integral Formula for complex integrals is defined as
$$
\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z - z_{0}} dz = 2 \pi i \cdot n(\gamma , z_{0}) \cdot f(z_{0})
$$

What does the function $n(\gamma , z_{0})$ denote in this context, and how can I calculate it for specific values of $\gamma$ and $z_{0}$?

Thanks

Comment: That's the index of the contour around the point $z_0$. This basically just gives you the number of times the loop goes around that point

Comment: Thank you. How would this value be found though?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number

Comment: @TylerHG you might want to consider writing this as an answer so future readers don't initially think that the question is unanswered, and also so that the answer might be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is called the index of a contour or the winding number of a contour around some point $z_0$. Intuitively, it is the number of times a contour goes around this particular point. There are various ways of defining it all of which can be find on the associated Wikipedia page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number